# Storing fish shell aliases in another file

Tags: alias, fish

I have a `config.fish` in `~/.config/fish`. While editing my `fish_prompt` I accidentally deleted my aliases once. I *did have backup*, but I want to store all aliases separately from now on. Also, how can I auto-load all of my aliases when I `source` the newly-edited `config.fish`?

I have `alias update="source ~/.config/fish/config.fish"`. So if I make change to the location of my `config.fish` **and** edit the alias as necessary, next time I `update` the updated alias should reflect in the updated config. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things fish offers here:

- Files in ~/.config/fish/functions named after a function (plus a ".fish" ending) will be autoloaded once that function is called
- Files in ~/.config/fish/conf.d/ (with a ".fish" ending) will be sourced before config.fish

So you can either put your functions/aliases in a function file each, or put them in files in conf.d in whatever grouping you want.

Also you can put your fish_prompt in its own file - ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

(also "alias" is simply a cheesy helper function to make functions - the core shell has no concept of aliases)